# How to cut out noisy and complicated object in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

is here anyone who could recommend me some good step by step technique on how to cut out complex objects?

For example this medusa.
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: There are [*dozens* of posts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=background+removal) at this site regarding background removal. Have you tried *anything* yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Channels as a starting point to make a mask.

1. Control CTRL+click on a channel to make a selection from it, then back in the layers panel, add a layer mask.
2. Then you can edit the layer mask by selecting it, and paint on it directly.  If you set a soft-edged Brush to Overlay mode, and lower its opacity to around 50%, then you can paint in black to mask more, or paint in white to mask less areas.
3. You can also apply a curves or levels adjustment to the layer mask to try to improve it.

Example made using this technique

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would handle it for this image:

1. Make a rough cutout of the subject so there's less background information to visually process when you're editing.
2. Duplicate the layer.
3. Set the duplicate's blending mode to Multiply.
4. Ctrl+Alt+2
5. Use this selection for an inverted mask on your original cutout layer
6. Adjust the mask as necessary.

For the last step, I rely heavily on curves and selections.  You can use the transparency selection you made earlier to restrict what parts are affected by the curves tool.  Magic Wand with a 3x3 or 5x5 sample area is also okay.  Use the history brush to bring back really fragile areas like the tendril at the bottom.